# Is there a specifc reason why the default "Site Navigation" term set will only be shown inside the realted site collection Term Store Management

Tags: 2013, navigation, term-store, term-set, managed-metadata-service

sometimes i got totally confused on how sharepoint works "internally" and why we always get weird behavior. now today i wanted to create a new site collection of type Enterprise wiki and I want to keep the navigation setting equals to "managed navigation" with "friendly url". so i follow these steps:-

1. create a new site collection of type Enterprise Wiki.
2. Inside the "site settings >> Navigation", i kept the defualt setting as is:-
   [image]

now i noted this , when i access the Term Store from "Site Setting>>Term Store Management" to check the term set which will be storing the navigation terms i got the following (where sharepoint have automatically created a new Term Group named "Site Collection -- <>" + a new term set) :-
[image]

but the problem is that when i access the same managed metadata service from my "Central Administration" >> "Managed services" >> chose the "Managed Metadata service", i can not see the automatically create Term group, as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice on this ? as if i chose to manualy create a new Metadata group using the UI, then i will not have any option to hide the group from the central administration !!